# Magento 2: Issue with php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

when i run this command php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> /home/vitalticks/public_html/generated/code/Codazon/ThemeLayoutPro/Console/Command/BuildAssets/Interceptor.php" file can't be deleted. Warning!unlink(/home/vitalticks/public_html/generated/code/Codazon/ThemeLayoutPro/Console/Command/BuildAssets/Interceptor.php): Permission denied The "/home/vitalticks/public_html/generated/code/Codazon/ThemeLayoutPro/Console/Command/FixData/Interceptor.php" file can't be deleted. Warning!unlink(/home/vitalticks/public_html/generated/code/Codazon/ThemeLayoutPro/Console/Command/FixData/Interceptor.php): Permission denied

Comment: delete 'generated' folder and try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your permission of "generated" folder first.

set permission from CLI using below command :

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/

It may help you to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux based system than run following command.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 generated pub var
sudo chown root:root generated
```

(replace root:root with your system user)

Let me know if further help is required.

Answer (score 0):

if someone is using dockergento go inside a bash with command

```
dockergento bash --root
```

and use command mentioned above there.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```